# IPv4 broadcast routing in Linux

Tags: routing, ipv4

I have a server with three network interfaces- loopback interface `lo` and two physical network interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:09:f0:92:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 93.184.216.34/22 brd 93.184.219.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::21d:9ff:fef0:92ab/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:09:f0:92:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.228.2.2/24 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::21d:9ff:fef0:92ac/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now if I check the routing for 255.255.255.255 or 0.0.0.0.0(older IP broadcast address), then I would expect, that packet is forwarded on all three network interfaces. Instead, for 255.255.255.255 only the `eth0` is used and for 0.0.0.0 the `lo` is used:

```
root@server:~# ip route get 255.255.255.255
broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev eth0  src  93.184.216.34
    cache <local,brd> 
root@server:~# ip route get 0.0.0.0
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  src 127.0.0.1 
    cache <local> 
root@server:~#
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

`0.0.0.0` is not a broadcast address. Software often uses it as the "any" address, which might explain why it shows the first interface it finds. It is not routable in any case.

The `255.255.255.255` address isn't routable. When using it you'll have the specify the interface. It seems to show you the first broadcast-capable interface.

But in both cases the assumption that the addresses are routable is wrong, so I'm surprised that you're getting any information at all when trying to look up the routes.

Comment: My statement that 0.0.0.0 is a broadcast address came from [this](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipapp/configuration/12-4/iap-12-4-book/iap-bph.html) Cisco document where they say that `IP broadcast packets are sent to the destination IP broadcast address 255.255.255.255 (or the older but still occasionally used IP broadcast address of 000.000.000.000)`. However, I see your point. In Linux one needs to either specify the interface(for example with `-I` in case of `ping`) or modify the local routing table(for example `ip route add 255.255.255.255/32 dev eth1`).